# Google Geocoding API status check - OVER_QUERY_LIMIT

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google's geocoding API service allows 2,500 free call per day and when you hit the limit the status returns `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT`.

Is there a way to check the status before I make the call? I'd like to hide the component on the website if it's gone over the limit.

I've been looking for an endpoint to check the status but no look so far.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding

Comment: @SandeepBiradar It didn't sorry. I'm looking to programatically check before I make a call on the API so I can hide the element on the page if it's not going to work.

Comment: I'm looking exactly for that exact scenario. Did you ever manage to find something?

Answer (score 1):

**Monitoring APIs and capping usage**

You can view traffic reports and billing information for a project or API on your project home page. To navigate to your project home page, select the project name from the list at the top of the page.

Traffic reports are available only if there is recent usage. If available, there will be a graph on the project home page labeled API that shows the traffic. If there is no recent usage, then the traffic report is not displayed.

**To view traffic summaries for a specific API, do the following:**

> Go to the Google Developers Console.
>   From the projects list, select a project or create a new one.
>   Open the console menu  Gallery Menu  and select API Manager.
>   Click Enabled APIs.
>   Click the name of the API.
>   Click Quotas or Usage.
>   To view billing details if you have billing enabled, click Estimated charges this month under Billing.

**SRC:** https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_mapload
           https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158858

**The second link will provide you all the relevent info.**